# How to handle adaptive cards with mobile view

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Is there any way to be more specific with adaptive cards on mobile.

Here I'm using **bot-framework** with adaptive cards. More precisely, I am building *table view* in cards.

- Looking for adding **pagination** in the table.
- Adding **scrolling** in table.

Answer (score 0):

AdaptiveCards do not allow scrolling or paging.. But we can do with Carousel feature.Please check the below code:

```
{
   attachmentLayout: Attacenter code herehmentLayoutTypes.Carousel,
   attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard()]
}
```

Other work Around Solution,

If you want to implement paging you could add a "next page" button to your card, when pressed you just update the card with the new list data.

MS Teams allows you to update cards/message you already sent so you could send the first page and when a user clicks on the action button you sent the second page etc.